# how to CSS center a div, which is the child of a form element?

Tags: css, forms, html, center, alignment

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I have been trying forever to center this div:

```
<form>
    <div class="submitter">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" data-theme="e" />
            <input type="reset" value="reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

There is more stuff in the form, but I'm just interested in centering the controlgroup.

I have tried everything I know from `text-align` to `margin: 0 auto` but I can't get it to work. In my desparation, I set a fix width to the form and added the submitter element, which I'm expanding to `100%` and then setting the controlgroup to `display:inline-block` but I can't get it to work...

**Question**:
How to place the controlgroup in the center of the form?

THANKS!

**EDIT:**
here is my form 
[image]

Both columns are `ul` elements, `width:49%;display:inline;`

Comment: Do you have a diagram of your expected result?

Comment: I can post a screenshot, 1sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/fNYb4/

Using `margin: 0 auto;` on the inner div using an attribute selector seems to work.

```
div[data-role="controlgroup"]
{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Remember that the parent element needs a set width as well as the element to be centered.

Comment: I sure don't understand why it's working all of a sudden, but it seems using the attribute selector did the trick. THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome, be aware though that IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified. Attribute selection is NOT supported in IE6 and lower.

Comment: I'm `<!DOCTYPE html>`-ing. Thanks for the info. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Margin: 0 auto; works for me ( you should set width to your block beofre using margin:0 auto; )

CSS:

```
<style>
.one {
border:1px solid;
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="submitter">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="one">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" data-theme="e" />
            <input type="reset" value="reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first target the parent div...

Here is my [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5ghVM/) on jsFiddle

Comment: have it figured out. Thanks for answering.